# Why Does YYYYMMDD Fail in Databricks

Tags: databricks

Used the SQL query below in Oracle-Toad with no errors. Company switched to AWS Databricks and get the following error when I run the same query run in Oracle:

```
[INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.DATETIME_PATTERN_RECOGNITION]
You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
Fail to recognize 'YYYYMMDD' pattern in the DateTimeFormatter.
```

```
select Plan_ID, Rate_Area_ID, MMDays/30 MbrMth from                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        select substr(COMM_PLAN_ID,4,20)Plan_ID, A.RATE_AREA_ID, Sum (to_date(Disenrol_date,'YYYYMMDD') -to_date(Enrol_Date,'YYYYMMDD')) MMDays                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        from BI_RA_NM.ACA_PRIORITY_ENROLLMENT A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        where SUBSTR(COMM_PLAN_ID,1,10) IN ('1887NH087', '1886NH102',  '1885NH108')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        and Enrol_Date >= 20220101
        and enrol_date <= 20220831                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        Group By  substr(COMM_PLAN_ID,4,20), A.RATE_AREA_ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        Order by 1,2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        )
```

| Column A |
| --- |
| 422,333 |

The query run in Oracle would give a count of customer member months. Looking for a solution to DateTimeFormatter

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of differences between Oracle and Spark SQL dialects. In your query at least two are significant:

- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) uses different date pattern than [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). You should use `yyyyMMdd` not `YYYYMMDD`
- Date differece in Oracle is number of days (integer), where in Spark it's [INTERVAL type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html). To get the difference in number of days use [datediff](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#datediff) function

Your query should then use following formula to calculate `MMDays`:

```
Sum (datediff(to_date(Disenrol_date,'yyyyMMdd'), to_date(Enrol_Date,'yyyyMMdd')))
```